# ASPX GridView header name?

Tags: asp.net

How do we access the header above the edit and delete buttons? I would like to put some text there instead of it being empty.

Comment: What is the column type of Edit and Delete?

Comment: Using a template field with a linkbutton would do the trick...you have to set header text. There is one particular CommandName value you have to give, I guess its `edit`. It is something like reserved for gridview use...additionally you'd have to manually write code to add/remove buttons once user enters/leaves the edit mode. There are reserved CommandName values for each kind of button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
            <Columns>
             <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="btnInsert" runat="server" 
                Text="Insert" CommandName="Insert" ForeColor="White" />
            </HeaderTemplate>
           </asp:TemplateField>
           <asp:CommandField HeaderText="Edit" ShowEditButton="True" />
           <asp:CommandField HeaderText="Delete" ShowDeleteButton="True" />
           </Columns>
         </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add text to header column to gridview column of edit button.

```
  <asp:GridView ID="grdviewlst" runat="server" >
                    <Columns>

                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Actions">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Button ID="btnedit" CssClass="btnclassedit" runat="server" CommandName="EDIT"
                                    Text="Edit" ToolTip="Edit" />

                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
```